# Number of entries in IloExpr

Tags: constraints, cplex

I'm creating a CPLEX LP (C++) and am creating constraints using IloExpr in the usual way. eg.

```
IloExpr cons(m_env);

for (auto& pID : values) {

    if (pID != -1) {
        cons += variables[pID];
    }
}

m_model.add(IloRange(m_env, 0.0, cons, 1.0));
```

At the end of the loop, cons may not have any variables if all values are -1.  I'd like to check this to avoid adding an empty constraint to the model.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is not really a CPLEX issue but you could use a binary variable to remember whether you have added a non empty variable:

```
IloExpr cons(m_env);

int empty=1;

for (auto& pID : values) {

    if (pID != -1) {
        cons += variables[pID];
        empty=0;
    }
}

if (empty==0) m_model.add(IloRange(m_env, 0.0, cons, 1.0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex.

I get that I can add a binary variable to say whether I have added an entry.  Also I could define a IloExpr::LinearIterator at the end of the loop and check the .ok() value to see if entries have been added.

But usually CPLEX class properties have direct methods to access them.  And whether there are variables or not in an added constraint seems pretty important!  So I'm looking for and am expecting to find a CPLEX call that will tell me if IloExpr has entries of not.

Comment: Actually I may have figured this out.  I think I can use:

if (cons.getLinearIterator().ok()) {

}